# Remove black frames from a videos

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any way to remove & replace black frames from a video without losing video quality? There are like just 3-4 frames to be removed.
[I tried this method, but the result was nt that great and the video was heavily compressed](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23589/replace-black-frames-with-previous-frames#new-answer)
This is 2022 and thought may be there any better ways to do it now. :)

Comment: The filters will remain the same. You have to add some video encoding parameters. Try adding `-c:v libx264 -crf 18`

Comment: @Gyan I did try that. I used ffv1 instead. But it didn't fix my black screen issue (but the video quality was fine). Even though it got heavily compressed, the one with no video encoding parameters had better results.